# Not able to post some fields using createDraftListing API

Tags: php, json, api, etsy

We have implemented the createDraftListing API using this documentation to create new listing on etsy.

But we are not able to post below field using above API because in documentation request parameter this field are not present.

Also we have added the item weight, item length, item width and item height in request feed and posting this value to above api call but still showing blank on products.

Request feed:

```
   {
  "title": "this is my title",
  "description": "this is my description",
  "quantity": "100",
  "state": "active",
  "price": 44.55,
  "who_made": "collective",
  "when_made": "2020_2022",
  "listing_type": "physical",
  "shipping_profile_id": 12345678,
  "processing_min": 1,
  "processing_max": 1,
  "item_weight": "0.71",
  "item_weight_unit": "lb",
  "item_length": 5.5,
  "item_width": "7.5",
  "item_height": 0.75,
  "item_dimensions_unit": "in",
  "has_variations": false,
  "language": "en-US",
  "is_taxable": true,
  "should_auto_renew": true,
  "is_customizable": true,
  "is_personalizable": true,
  "personalization_is_required": true,
  "personalization_char_count_max": 1,
  "personalization_instructions": "",
  "taxonomy_id": 2279
}
```

So please let us know any api to post above fields to etsy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first you can get id shipping profile id in get shipping profile api. I try and success